# angular2dart components property and methods

Tags: dart

When look at docs for components, there are many methods, properties and more.
For what is that good for?

For example there is a `MaterialInputComponent` and property `errorMsg`, how can I use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/dart-lang/angular2_components/blob/master/lib/src/components/material_input/material_input.dart#L66

> ```
> /// - `errorMsg` -- The error msg to be shown on the input if the max characters
> ///   are hit or the msg for an invalid number in the case of type = "number"
> ```

Comment: How can I use that?

Comment: It's an input. https://github.com/dart-lang/angular2_components/blob/master/lib/src/components/material_input/material_input.dart#L118 `<material-input [errorMsg]="My custom error message">`.